# Loading pong style page Html/Css

Tags: html, css, loading, pong

I'm trying to do the same visual as this [fiddle](https://codepen.io/georgehastings/pen/ezEId/?editors=1100) but I don't have the bouncing ball. I get this result : (it's the exact same code copy/paste from the first fiddle example) What is the problem ?
I tested on Googlle Chrome and Firefox both have the same result.

```css
body {
  background: #8063ea;
}

.pong-loader {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 6px;
  background-color: transparent;
  animation: paddles 0.75s ease-out infinite;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  
  &:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 15px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: ballbounce 0.6s ease-out infinite;
  }
}

@keyframes paddles {
  0% {
    box-shadow: -25px -10px 0px #fff, 25px 10px 0px #fff;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: -25px 8px 0px #fff, 25px -10px 0px #fff;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: -25px -10px 0px #fff, 25px 10px 0px #fff;
  }
}

@keyframes ballbounce {
  0%{
    transform: translateX(-20px) scale(1,1.2);
  }
  25%{
    transform: scale(1.2,1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(15px) scale(1,1.2);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale(1.2,1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pong-loader"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codepen has [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/) and you pasted it as plain CSS. You can compile the SCSS into plain CSS using the codepen CSS menu and get the desired effect

```css
body {
  background: #8063ea;
}

.pong-loader {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 6px;
  background-color: transparent;
  animation: paddles 0.75s ease-out infinite;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.pong-loader:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 15px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: ballbounce 0.6s ease-out infinite;
}

@keyframes paddles {
  0% {
    box-shadow: -25px -10px 0px #fff, 25px 10px 0px #fff;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: -25px 8px 0px #fff, 25px -10px 0px #fff;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: -25px -10px 0px #fff, 25px 10px 0px #fff;
  }
}

@keyframes ballbounce {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-20px) scale(1, 1.2);
  }
  25% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(15px) scale(1, 1.2);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pong-loader"></div>
```

Comment: But why when I tested with html+css I find the same problem like if I was in css, I use <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>

Comment: What you see in the codepen isn't CSS. It's SCSS/SASS.

Comment: I understand ,I thought it was css but it's SCSS/SASS. I thought fiddle use SCSS and my code was Css ...